# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error -1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to deploy .Net 4.6.1 FW Web API application on IIS and I get this message.

[image: Error image]

I have .NET 4.5 and 4.6.1 installed and my application worked before, but after I ran the deployment through CIDI I get this.

Comment: Try to add IIS_IUSER to your application folder.

Comment: And if this is .Net core project, make sure your install dotnetcore host and sdk.

Comment: This problem occurs when the ApplicationHost.config file or the Web.config file contains a malformed or unsupported XML element. To resolve this issue Delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config file or from the Web.config file as indicated by the error message. [Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7/) and [link](https://forums.iis.net/t/1176834.aspx)